# Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Double'

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

I am making an ASP.NET Core 3 (Preview) MVC CRUD application using MongoDb using MongDb.Driver nuget package.

I have created an ASP.NET Core 3 MVC app with a default Home Controller and Index view. I have added Customer model as follows :

Customer model:

```
public class Customer
{

   [BsonId]

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Home Controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {

    private IMongoCollection<Customer> collection;
    public HomeController()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase("CustomerDatabase");
        this.collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Customer>("Customers");
    }



    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = collection.Find(FilterDefinition<Customer>.Empty).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

cshtml :

```
 <h1>List of Customers</h1>



 <h2>@TempData["Message"]</h2>
   <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Insert"> Add New Customer</a>

   <hr />

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
    <td>@item.Name</td>
    <td>@item.Age</td>
    <td>@item.Salary</td>
    <td>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Update" asp-route- 
id="@item.Id">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Delete" asp-route- 
  id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>

}

  </table>
```

On running the app, getting an error message : Message=An error occurred while deserializing the Id property of class MongoDb.ASP.NETCore3CRUDSample.Models.Customer: Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Double'.

Comment: You have a record in your customers collection where the id is a double.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you let me know what I should do to get rid of the error?

Comment: Find the record and assign it a proper id, or delete it if it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Codecaster. I have now sorted it myself (sorry I didn't update my comments earlier), and the issue was in setting up the MongoDb database where I mixed the records with one set having the auto generated Object Id (alongwith CustomerID) and other set having only _id as the Customer ID field(that doesn't requireauto generation of object ID). I have now removed the earlier records and redid the collections to have unform ID fields across all the records.